# PyQt Creating a QDialog inside a QMainWindow

Tags: pyqt, qmainwindow, qdialog

i am learning PyQt and tried to put a QDialog inside a QMainWindow (to mix layouts). I just don't get why i have 2 separated windows instead of my Dialog inside the MainWindow.

Tks in advance.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore

class Btns(QtGui.QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Btns, self).__init__(parent)
        grid = QtGui.QGridLayout(self)
        self.setLayout(grid)
        btnv=QtGui.QPushButton("valider")
        grid.addWidget(btnv, 0,0)
        btna=QtGui.QPushButton("annuler")
        grid.addWidget(btna,0,1)
        btns=QtGui.QPushButton("sortir")
        grid.addWidget(btns, 1,1)
        btnr=QtGui.QPushButton("retour")
        grid.addWidget(btnr, 1,0)
        self.show()

class MaFenetre(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MaFenetre, self).__init__()
        self.initMb()
        self.initBtns()


    def initMb(self):
        menu_bar = self.menuBar()
        file_menu = menu_bar.addMenu('&Fichier')


    def initBtns(self):
        btns = Btns(self)

def main():
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    mf = MaFenetre()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 1):

> The QDialog class is the base class of dialog windows. A dialog window is a top-level window mostly used for short-term tasks and brief communications with the user.

[Source: Qt Documentation on [QDialog](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qdialog.html)]

QDialog is supposed to make a new window! If you don't want a new window, don't use a `QDialog`. Consider using `QWidget` instead.